# Google Places detail "photos[]" jsonarray is always null

Tags: java, android, json

So I get place_id by storing it in a Hashmap with the "name" of the place as the key.

```
private HashMap<String, String> placeTitleId = new HashMap<>();

if (!place.isNull("place_id")) {
    placeId = place.getString("place_id");
    placeTitleId.put(name, placeId);
}
```

Later, I create the Places Detail search url:

```
private String createPlaceDetailsUrl(String placeId) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?");
            stringBuilder.append("placeid=").append(placeId);
            stringBuilder.append("&key=").append(GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY);
            return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Finally, I parse the json response:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);
if (data.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
    JSONArray photoArray = data.getJSONArray("photos");
}
```

What I don't understand is why the "photos" json array has no value
Android Monitor: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for photos

The documentation says that the photos[] jsonarray should have up to 10 photos. However, the json output schema does not contain a photos[] object, which I find weird. Is there a problem with how I am obtaining place_id or parsing the response?

**EDIT:**

The "result" String is incredibly long, but I can provide a gist:

```
result {
"address components" : [
      *bunch of stuff*
]
...
"geometry" : {
      *bunch of stuff*
}
"icon"
"id"
"photos" : [
 {
      "height"
      "html_attributions:
      "photo_reference!!
 }
 {
     ...
     "photo_reference!!
 }
 *bunch more of these*
]
}
```

EDIT:
Fix is getting json object "result

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("result");
```

The data object has "pictures"

Comment: What does your JSONData contain? You'd probably debug there and check that if there is somethig about `photos` in that.

Comment: My JSONData contains the details of one place returned by the places detail request. According to the documentation, the "photos" object should have some value. I've tested multiple places too and they all return an empty "photos" object.

Comment: Hit the URL which you're passing to the server in a browser and check that if it actually contains the `photos` or not.

Comment: You can show `result` data .@user3131097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);
 // add log here ,make sure you have photos in your result
 Log.e("result", result + "");
 if (data.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
     // edited here
     JSONArray photoArray = data.optJSONArray("photos");
 }
```

**Edit**

```
if (data .has("photos")) {
     Log.e("photos", "photos exists");
 } else  {
     Log.e("photos", "photos not exists");
}
```

Use `data .has("photos")` in your code and judge it  .

**Note**

Use

```
JSONObject data  = new JSONObject(result);
    if(data.has("TAG")){
    // if has it in your data,do something
}
```

to determine whether this tag is present in the data

Comment: data.optJSONArray("photos") did not throw any error. However, when I check the length of of the array: Android Monitor: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: Using `optJSONArray` method, you won't report an exception directly when you get a nonexistent value, but return an empty string

Comment: Ah, I see. I provided a summarized view of the result string. Most importantly, the photos array is not empty and it does indeed have multiple photo_reference strings.

Comment: I did not see that `height` 、`html_attributions` and `photo_reference` have the their value . Only key in it .@user3131097

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details If you go to Place Detail Results, each photos object in the array should have four son objects, height, width, html_attributions, and photo_reference. You can assume that they have values. I did not provide it in the original post, but values do appear in the Android Monitor.

Comment: I didn't see photos key in the json data you put.[https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)@user3131097

Comment: By photos key, do you mean the google place detail api key because I add that when building the url.

Comment: Make sure that the position you added is correct 。@user3131097